# Format group of data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to group rows which is having same Name in `DataGridView` as shown below. Is it possible to implement it without using any third party i searched alot it is giving me result in visual basic i want it in window forms c#

```
Original DataTable: 
A      | B
-------|-----------
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 4
2      | 5
```

Result

```
A      | B    
-------|--------------
1      | 1
       | 2
       | 3
2      | 4
       | 5
```

Comment: If you got the solution but in `VB.NET` language, you can convert those codes to `C#` using [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Perhaps the following (has image to show how it will display) which is a custom DataGridView. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44622c0-74e1-463b-97b9-27b87513747e/windows-forms-data-controls-and-databinding-faq?forum=winformsdatacontrols#faq8

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Just by simply putting a span behaviour in your DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

Try to open this link for more details.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34037/DataGridVewTextBoxCell-with-Span-Behaviour

Hope this helps.